# Multiple Junit Test Cases at a time

Tags: junit, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to hit a few Junit Test Cases at a time using the Junit Sampler in Jmeter and want to get the result of each of individually.

Eg:
JunitTestCase1
JunitTestCase2
JunitTestCase3

Want to hit all of them parallel and want to get their results(load time) individually.

Answer (score 0):

1. To execute several requests at exactly the same moment - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
2. Get individual results - use [JMeter Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice, the most informative (and the most resource consuming as well) is [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate thread group for each test case, then add a JUnit Sampler for each thread group. You will be able to select a different test in the JUnit Sampler dropdowns for each one.  [It should look a bit like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44PVK.png)

To get their load times individually you can add a Results Tree or Response Times over Time Listener to each thread group. Bear in mind this will be the total time including opening the browser (if you are opening a browser). If you don't want that included in the times you will need to add some sort of logging to your test code to collect the metrics.